# Undefined object angular after subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, undefined, http-get

I try to get data from my server.
Inside my subscribe function I have data but when i try to use it outside
function console.log return undefined

Service:

```
getPostDetail():Observable<Post> {
    return this.http.get<Post>(this.detailPostUrl);
}
```

Component:

```
export class PostDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    post: Post;

    constructor(private postsService:PostsService) {
        this.postsService.getPostDetail().subscribe(data => {
            this.post = data;
            console.log(this.post);
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.post); // undefined
    }
}
```

I see that first I get a `undefined` from `ngOnInit`'s `console.log()` but I don't know how to change it.
I can add that I have very similar function and that one works.
Anyone can help ?

Comment: Javascript http calls are always async, meaning that ngOnInit will be executed before ur data came back as a response from the server. Thats why it is undefined. Where do u want to use it?

Comment: you dont undrestand that this.postsService.getPostDetail().subscribe is asyncronuos. So you don't know when the data is resolved.

ngOnInit() is exextued when the componente is initialized after the costructor, but you not aware if data is resolved before the ngOnInit invocation;

You should study better the rxjs library

Comment: Why do you need to check the `this.post` in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook? You should implement your logic in the callback (your subscription handler)

Comment: @Pieterjan even better would to not manually subscribe ...

Comment: I want to use it to display data.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments above indicate, http calls are asynchronous, meaning it takes some time for their results to come back from the service call.  The getPostDetail() subscription in the constructor does not block execution, and the ngOnInit() method will be called before any data comes back. That's why this.post is undefined.

Instead, I would put the call to getPostDetail() in ngOnInit, and put any logic that requires this.Post in the subscription handler, as Pierterjan recommends.

If your UI is expecting to bind to this.Post, then you should use the elvis operator:

```
<div>{{Post?.postDate}}</div>
```

This will not throw an error while Post is null or undefined.  It just won't display until the service call completes.

Comment: BTW I should add that Post is a name collision with http.post.  It may not be a problem, but to keep things clear I'd consider renaming it to blogPost or something that makes sense in your domain model.